# What does the vertical bar mean in $ \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\rvert $

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, notation

I want to know what the symbol '|' besides a function means.
For example:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\rvert
$$

Comment: it means substitute

Answer (score 2):

The partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $x=2$. Written in $\LaTeX$ as `\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big{|}_{x=2}` or alternatively use `\right\rvert`

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big{|}_{x=2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It is an old-fashioned piece of notation. The vertical bar is often used to mean that we must insert the conditions in the expression. For partial derivatives my humble opinion is that we should not use it regularly. The standard notation is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0),
$$
like we do for a generic function of two variables in modern analysis.

Comment: I disagree that it is "old-fashioned".

Comment: It seems to me that it is used to avoid the modern idea of function. A function is never $f(x)$, it is $f$. So why should we write $f|_{x=x_0}$ instead of $f(x_0)$?

Comment: Not all functions have to be given names.  For example $$x^2\vert_{x=3}$$ is better than something like $$(x \mapsto x^2)(3).$$  We need substitutions as well as function evaluations in modern-day mathematical writing.

Comment: I vote for the second piece of notation. The first one is a typical case of value-instead-of-name, and as such obsolete in contemporary mathematics. I agree that people may like it as they liked it in 1800, but I cannot encourage it. Actually I would suggest $\left( \# \mapsto \#^2 \right)(3)$.